# Online Chat Application error - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

so i'm making an online chat application and when i try to connect i get this message. Im certain that the code is right but i think its a setting on the PC or in the firewall thats blocking my connection. Can anyone help ?

```
**server.js**- const io = require('socket.io')(3000)

io.on('connection', socket => {
socket.emit('chat-message', 'Hello World')
}) 

**script.js** - const socket = io('https://localhost:3000')

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
console.log(data)
}) 

**package.json** - {
"name": "npm",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"devStart": "nodemon server.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"@types/socket.io": "^2.1.10",
"socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
 "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
 }
}
```